# How to 301 redirect old indexed pages to my new page

Tags: .htaccess

i have 100k indexed pages in google

http://www.domain.com/lol-1
http://www.domain.com/lol-2
http://www.domain.com/lol-3
...

I wanted to 301 redirect all the 100k page to my new page at http://www.domain.com/newpage

how do i do this? sorry i am new to htaccess

Comment: This is easily achieved with `mod_rewrite` for Apache. Did you try reading the documentation? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: i read it, but my questions is how to cater for that 100k urls that was indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will mathc anything accessing your server starting with lol- and send the rest of the url onto newpage/

That is www.domain.com/lol-whatever --> www.domain.com/newsite/whatever

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lol-(.+)$ newpage/$1 [R=301]
```

If what follows lol- has to be a number, use the following more pecific case:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lol-([0-9]+)$ newpage/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Hi the lol is just a sample. i have url that does not follow a common pattern.

Comment: e.g.

    www.domain.com/Neda_fx
    www.domain.com/derek_fx

Comment: So will you redirect from one domain to another (i.e www.domain.com/xx --> www.domain2.com/xx)? Or internally on the same domain (www.domain.com/xxx -> www.domain.com/asdf/xxx) ?

Comment: Is there a common pattern on what the urls you redirect from or the url(s) you want to redirect to?

Comment: nah, there is no common pattern. nevertheless i resolved the problem. thanks everyone. seems that what i am doing is a suicide in SEO..

Comment: So what did you end up doing? Nothing?